What's the meaning behind Deadpool's joke about Gambit looking like a "superhero version of Hawkeye"?
In Deadpool & Wolverine (2024), there's a scene where Deadpool meets Gambit. In true Deadpool fashion, Deadpool cracks a joke, saying Gambit "looks like the superhero version of Hawkeye."

Deadpool: And who's this succulent reminder of my own inadequacies? Look at you. You look like the superhero version of Hawkeye.

This joke left me a bit puzzled, as Gambit and the MCU's Hawkeye don't share any obvious similarities in terms of their appearance or abilities, besides both having the color purple incorporated into their costumes.
Just because they both wear purple, does that make Gambit the "superhero version" of Hawkeye? After all, they are both established superheroes in their own right, and the movie and TV show versions of Hawkeye have arguably undertaken more superheroics than the movie and TV show versions of Gambit.
What's Deadpool getting at here? Is Deadpool taking a playful jab at Hawkeye, suggesting he's not quite superhero material? If so, where does this idea come from? Or is there some other connection between these characters that I'm missing?

I think it was the purple outfit...no?

@Paulie_D It's possible. But just because they both wear purple, does that really make Gambit the "superhero version" of Hawkeye? They're both superheroes, so there must be more to it than just the color scheme.

Hawkeye, strictly speaking, doesn't have any superpowers. Gambit however does. Therefore Deadpool may not consider Hawkeye a "real" superhero, making Gambit a "superhero version" of Hawkeye (with powers). Not posting as an answer though, this is just speculation.

@Tronman That's interesting; however, I'm not sure Deadpool's joke is necessarily a dig at Hawkeye's lack of superpowers (one could even argue that Hawkeye's unnatural marksmanship is an actual superpower). After all, Batman has no superpowers, and nobody would deny that he's a superhero. One could even argue that Hawkeye has more superpowers than Batman.

Consider: SNL 2012, "Hawkeye Disappoints the Avengers" (feat. Jeremy Renner) -- https://youtu.be/WUfnQPoJbSc

Or Renner as Hawkeye on the Tonight Show singing, "Maybe I'm as super as they are" based on his scarf collection, trombone playing, cat's Instagram, etc.: https://youtu.be/PJkg9B8MgCo

To quote Sheldon Cooper, "Nobody ever says help, Hawkeye".
